# Linking to file not in website root?

Tags: html, ubuntu, hyperlink

Hi hope someone can help, I have the following little problem:

Ubuntu server 64bit current release running 2 virtual websites

Folder structure

**site1** (This site is available to the web)

/var/www/site1

**site2** (intranet)

/var/www/site2

/var/www/site2/pdf/order_pdf/ (folders where .pdfs are stored)

So from site1 I have tried to link to a file contained in site2 with the following:

```
<a href="../site2/pdf/prder_pdf/filename.pdf
```

This doesn't seem to work, hope someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line to the Virtual hots file for site1 /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file

```
Alias /pdf /var/www/site2/pdf/Order_pdf
```

and now working a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Relative URIs are relative to the base *URI*, not the file system of the web server.

If you want to link to something on a different site then you must use an absolute URI (e.g. `http://example.com/...`) or a scheme relative URI (e.g. `//example.com/...`).

Comment: So because the files are in the intranet site I will be unable to link to them?

Comment: On an Ubuntu server is it possible to map that folder from site2 so it becomes available to the files in site1 ?

Comment: No, you just have to give the URL to them. Obviously anybody on the Internet will be able to follow the link (since they won't have access to the Intranet).

Comment: Yes. That's what the [alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) does. (I'm assuming you are using Apache, the operating system doesn't really matter). Then the files will have URIs on the Internet facing site as well as the Intranet.

Comment: Yes using apache2 (many thanks) hope there are some tutorials on the web re setting this up :)

Comment: would somebody be able to give an example of what I need to put in the .htaccess file? (sorry for the noobo question)

Comment: See the other end of the link in my last comment. No idea if you can do aliasing in htaccess. You may have to edit the main server config.